# React-native importing throws 'Unable to resolve module', even though IDE finds it prefectly

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo

[image]Here is my test import I use in App.js

```
import {test} from './utils/configs';
```

Here is my ./utils/configs:

```
export const test = 'test-string'
```

App.js and Utils folder are in a same level. IDE finds import perfectly, but Xcode simulator throws error: 
    Unable to resolve module `./utils/configs` from `/Users/riku/Documents/StreamrLabs/streamr-ios-location-poc/App.js`: The module `./utils/configs` could not be found from `/Users/riku/Documents/StreamrLabs/streamr-ios-location-poc/App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `/Users/User/Documents/Folder/projectname/utils/configs(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
- `/Users/User/Documents/Folder/projectname/utils/configs/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`

It seems that importing new modules breaks Xcode/bundler. My app is detatched expo app.

Comment: Hi ! What is the name of your config file ? Could you send us a screenshot/explain the tree of your folder ?
Then, check the error message: none of this files exist : `/Users/User/Documents/Folder/projectname/utils`
It's not the same path as above

Comment: I added image of my folder structure. I strongly think that this is issue with expo/xcode environments.

Comment: Try renaming config in config.js : Xcode is trying to find .js files, and here, there is no extension !

Comment: I have also tried both {test} and test way to import.

Comment: You should use {test} when you are exporting something but not as default.
If you are using `export default test;`, then, you can use `import test from ...`. With `export test` you have to use `import {test} from ...`

Comment: Man thank you! So simple bug, which I spent so much time to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files should have an extension ! (configs.js in this case).

Xcode is trying to find .js files, and here, there is no extension !

(solution for record)